# Nginx rewrite : how to remove everything after extension of a file

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

There are a lot of bad request of images and files on my site... but with names close from the real name. basically, if i have a file called example.gif, there is a call to example.gifzerzer. What i want is to rewrite to keep the name and the extension, but nothing after it.

I did create a map file with rewrite (it's working for example the tmp.php to index.php rewrite below except the rule for removing everything after extension).

Here is what i've done so far :

```
/(.+\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png|svg)).+ /$1;
```

this is not working neither

```
/(.+\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png|svg)).+? /$1;
```

my map :

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
  default "";
  /(.+\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png|svg)).+ /$1;
  /tmp.php /index.php;
}
```

i was under Apache before migrating to Nginx and this was working :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-/_]*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png|svg)).+ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: note that if i put only the rewrite in the server part, without using map, the rewrite is working (except that it does'nt change the url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that rewrite that is working, when put in the server section, but then it is not included in the map.

```
location ~ (.+\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png|svg)).+$ {
    return 301 /$1;
}
```

if someone has an idea why, or can confirm that i'm doing it right ?